# How to solve this particular differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

for this question I'm stuck on solving the following equation. Can anyone please help me out? Here's what I have so far

$$\dfrac{du}{dt} = \dfrac{1-t-u}{t+u}$$

$du = (\frac{1}{t+u} -1) dt $

Comment: Introduce $v(t) = u(t) + t$, then $v'(t) = u'(t) + 1$ so that $v'(t) - 1 = \frac{1-v}{v}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\dfrac{du}{dt} = \dfrac{1-t-u}{t+u}$$
$$u'=\dfrac {1}{t+u}-1$$
$$u'+1=\dfrac {1}{t+u}$$
$$(u+t)'=\dfrac {1}{t+u}$$
That's easy to integrate now.
$$\int (u+t)\, d(u+t)=\int \, dt$$
$$(u+t)^2=2t+C$$

Comment: Where did (u++t)' come from?

Comment: $u'+1=(u+t)'$ this is why @user6789

Comment: Ohh I see. I figured it out now I think, thanks

Comment: You're very welcome. I added more lines. @user6789